# Having trouble deserializing a JSON object that contains SF Ids

Tags: json, deserialize

I am using an geocoding API called [Geocodio](http://geocod.io/) to process a batch of addresses. I felt I had a good handle on deserializing JSON arrays, but am having trouble deserializing a response that doesn't have properties explicitly defined. Instead it returns an object that maps results to my Salesforce Ids. Here is a sample response:

```
{
  "results" : {
    "001e000000JCXuFAAX" : {
      "query" : "dfwdfw, New Ashford, MA  01237",
      "response" : {
        "error" : "Could not geocode address. Postal code or city required."
      }
    },
    "001e000000JCv8hAAD" : {
      "query" : "dfwdfw, Cambridge, MA  02138",
      "response" : {
        "error" : "Could not geocode address. Postal code or city required."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I choose to use `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` to convert the string response to an object:

```
String s = response.getBody();
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
Object results = m.get('results');
```

However, I'm lost trying to figure out to access properties inside the object. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
for(Account act : actList) {
    String id = (String) act.Id;
    Object result = results.get(id);
    //Now run logic to assign Latitude and Longitude values to Account object
}
```

Executing this code will throw: `[OPERATION FAILED]: [Line: 29, Column: 21] Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Object].get(String)`

Comment: I answered but should have first asked exactly what is at line 29?

Comment: You assumed correctly, it was `Object result = results.get(id);` Also tried, recasting it and worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to cast the results to the type you know them to be so that the compiler knows that there is a `get` method:

```
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) m.get('results');
```

Repeat the casting as you go down through the layers.